# Error : Error in Google Request , while try to get record from google spread sheet with library Help "google-api-php-client"

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I am trying to verify google spread sheet data from my php code , for update in sheet

I have used "google-api-php-client" library with php

I am authenticated successfully , and shared my sheet with client email address also.

my code is below,

```
 $ss = new Google_Spreadsheet('Item Demo', 'Sheet1');



$rows = $ss->getRows(array("sq" => "model=" . $modelrs[0]->name));

echo"<pre>";print_r($rows);die;
```

Here it gives me error that : `Error in Google Request`

can you tell me what is issue here ???

Comment: is there any solution for above error

Comment: this error is comming on serve only ,in my local it working proper